# adding textures to illustrator fonts

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, typefaces, line-art

I'm not sure where to look for these resources, but I'm trying to create an Art Nouveau style logo. What I would like to do is have the actual text be shape similar to what is in Carl Jungs redbook.  any suggestions on how to create this effect?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing automated within Illustrator to create such an effect.

You would need to plan then draw things manually.

I would probably draw it all by hand on paper, then scan and use the scan as a tracing template within Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

As Scott said, that is very much a custom piece you're referencing. You aren't going to find a good solution in AI.

On the other hand, if you don't have the luxury of investing a lot of time in this and you're willing to compromise on the perfection of it, you can just fill the type with a pattern. Even a custom pattern would take less time than drawing this by hand. And then, of course, when edits come in you won't have heartburn over it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ummmmm you *could* free hand this but if you're a computer artist and not a hand artist then all you would have to do is create your very detailed artwork, set a typeface over it, select the type, Object -> Expand, and then Object -> Clipping Mask -> Make.

You will have you detailed artwork cutout in the shape of the type you've overlaid on top of it. There's nothing impossible about it.